# Unable to connect GoogleApiClient instance from different activity than it created

Tags: android, multithreading, connection, google-api-client

I am facing some strange issue. I am creating an instance of `GoogleApiClient` in `MainActivity` class in `onCreate()` method. I am getting logged in Google account's complete information.

> MainActivity.java

```
GoogleApiClient google_api_client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          google_api_client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .build();
}

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
          MemoryStore.setGoogle_api_client(google_api_client);
          Log.d("", "isConnected=" + google_api_client.isConnected()); // Prints true.
    }
```

I am storing this instance in common class namely `MemoryStore.java`.

> MemoryStore.java

```
    private static GoogleApiClient google_api_client;

    public static GoogleApiClient getGoogle_api_client() {
        return google_api_client;
    }

    public static void setGoogle_api_client(GoogleApiClient client) {
        google_api_client = client;
    }
```

Now in another activity class say `FriendsListActivity.java`, I am disconnecting this GoogleApiClient on button click. Before that I am checking if that instance is connected or not in different methods of class.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("", "isConnected=" + MemoryStore.getGoogle_api_client().isConnected()); // Prints true.
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("", "isConnected=" + MemoryStore.getGoogle_api_client().isConnected()); // Prints false.
    }
```

To my surprise, it always say **`google_api_client` is disconnected in `onClick()`** method and always say **`google_api_client` is connected in `onCreate()` or `onResume()` method**.

 
Even I checked with **AlertDialog** to confirm before disconnecting, there as well I am getting instance **disconnected** on the click of `OK` button.

 
Can there be a problem with ui threads? like I am accessing instance from other than main thread?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After disconnecting the GoogleApiClient, set the object in the MemoryStore class to null.

`MemoryStore.setGoogle_api_client(null);`

Whenever you want it again, set it again the way you have done it in the MainActivity

Comment: But I am not getting isConnected() = false in FriendsListActivity in onClick() method, so not able to disconnect it. Not sure, from when it got disconnected.

Comment: You're saying that in onCreate() you get isConnected() as true but not in onClick()?

Comment: Yes. U read it correct. I am not sure, how it happened. Neither I am disconnecting it from anywhere.

Comment: Try setting `MemoryStore.setGoogle_api_client(google_api_client);` in the onCreate() of the MainActivity instead of onPause(). The onPause may not be getting called when you switch to another activity